# Jest and Angular: Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment'

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, configuration

I have Angular projects with Jest in place for unit testing. I'm trying to unit test a certain service that has environment variable as private property and if I run the test, it fails with the following information - Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment' from 'src/app/resources/services/resources.service.ts'

[image: project file structure]

```
 FAIL  src/app/resources/services/resources.service.test.ts
```

● Test suite failed to run

```
Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment' from 'src/app/resources/services/resources.service.ts'

Require stack:
  src/app/resources/services/resources.service.ts
  src/app/resources/services/resources.service.test.ts

  1 | import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> 2 | import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    | ^
  3 | import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
  4 | import { Resource } from '../models/resources';
  5 | import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

  at Resolver._throwModNotFoundError (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:427:11)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/resources/services/resources.service.ts:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/app/resources/services/resources.service.test.ts:7:1)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.484 s

**jest.config.ts**

```js
// require('jest-preset-angular/ngcc-jest-processor');

globalThis.ngJest = {
  skipNgcc: true,
  tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json', // this is the project root tsconfig
};

/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/src/environment/environment'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
};
```

**setupJest.ts**

```js
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
import './jest-global-mocks';
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: typo. `import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';` is relative and I bet you don't have a src directory in your services directory. The path should be `import { environment } from '../environments/environment'` or related relative path. No way to know since there's no file structure information in your post.

Comment: adding relative path solved the issue - thanks @E.Maggini